# Не передаются данные методом POST JS+PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет!

Не могу понять, почему в одном месте функция добавления записи в БД (связка JS+PHP) отрабатывает, а в другом нет.
Смысл следующий: пользователь вводит в поля некие значения, нажимаем добавить запись, после чего JS подхватывает значения из полей ввода и передает на обработку в PHP, где они уже добавляются в БД. 
Вот только почему-то в ветку условия на PHP, данный код не попадает (аналогичным образом реализовано еще несколько обработчиков - там работает успешно).
echo " alert(".$need_func.") "; -  возвращает пусто.

Есть следующая связка JS+HTML:

```js
function insert_corp_clients(name_comp, name_client, super_client) {

  //document.getElementById('button_corp_client_edit').className ="hidden";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'lib.php',
    data: {
      'type_responce': 'insert_corp_client_pres',
      'name_comp': name_comp,
      'name_client': name_client,
      'super_client': super_client
    }, //параметры запроса
    response: 'text', //тип возвращаемого ответа text либо xml

    success: function(data) { //возвращаемый результат от сервера
      $('.results').html(data);
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<form>
  
  <p>Введите Имя пользователя:
    <input type="text" name="name_comp_clients" />
  </p>
  <p>Права аккаунт менеджера:
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec_super" />
  </p>
  <input name="page" type="hidden" value="auth" />
  <input name="page_auth" type="hidden" value="none_corp" />
  <p>
    <input type="submit" id="insert_corp_clients1" onclick="insert_corp_clients(window.corp_client, name_comp_clients.value, chec_super.checked) " name="press1" value="Создать запись">
  </p>
</form>
```

На PHP обработчик следующий :

```
 $need_func=trim($_POST['type_responce']);
    if ($need_func=='insert_corp_client_pres') {
            echo "<script> alert(4) </script>";
    insert_company_clients(trim($_POST['name_comp']),trim($_POST['name_client']),trim($_POST['super_client']));
    }
```

Comment: Кто такие window.corp_client, name_comp_clients.value, chec_super.checked в html коде и как они связаны с DOM ?

Comment: window.corp_client - задается как глобальная переменная в другой JS функции window.corp_client = company_name (последовательность запуска соблюдена);
name_comp_clients.value, chec_super.checked - задаются пользователем, выше есть HTML код , дублирую
 <input type="text" name="name_comp_clients" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="chec_super" />


С точки зрения DOM - это конструкция находится внутри блоков <body> <div> (для каждого логического элемента выделен свой div блок)

Comment: хорошо бы открыть консоль в браузере (F12 в Chrome) и посмотреть что именно уходит на сервер во вкладке "Network". По крайней мере будет понятно на какой стороне проблема.

Comment: Нужно вам учится базовой отладке. В web-е это первостепенно, и отладка JS и PHP - элементарны. Предыдущий комментарий верен - посмотрите ещё Firebug для фаерфокса, лидер отладщиков. И посмотрете комбинацию ф-й php `var_dump($_POST);die();`

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Установил Firebug, на вкладке network можно увидеть следующий запрос на сторону PHP обработчика
name_client rdsrfdsf
name_comp Company1
super_client true
type_responce  insert_corp_client_pres

Т.е. type_responce уходит на PHP обработчик, видимо проблема где-то на стороне сервера (код обработчика приводил выше). Причину пока не понял...